# After accepting a connection, my STREAM socket gives the error 103 after just 30 seconds

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, pybluez

I am trying the develop a program (in python 3) in which it is possible to transfer a certain amount of data from a computer to another with bluetooth (using pybluez). After a client connects to the device, for some reason, the server side of the application raises a BluetoothError exception after around 30 seconds. It raises the following exception:

bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (103, 'Software caused connection abort')

I thought that I could be something in my code, so I decided to do a simpler version, in order to test it. I got the exact same error.

The following code is the simpler version I talked about previously.

This is the server side

```
from bluetooth import *

x = BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
print("bind")
x.bind(("", 1))
print("listen")
x.listen(1)
print("accepting")
conn, _ = x.accept()
print("reading")
print(conn.recv(256).decode('utf-8'))
print("closing")
conn.close()
x.close()
```

This is the client side

```
from bluetooth import * 
x = BluetoothSocket(RFCOMM)
x.connect((<addr>,1))
```

NOTE: the client side is not executed from a file, but writen directly in the python shell

After putting the server side script running on a regular computer and the client side script on a raspberry pi 3 with raspbian I get the BluetoothError after 30 seconds. The exception is raised on the line:

```
print(conn.recv(256).decode('utf-8'))
```

During this time I am able to send messages from one side to another. No matter what I do, after 30 seconds, the exception is raised.

I have no idea of what is happening. I am going to try with another computer with the client script, but it is getting complicated (windows, am I right :p).

Comment: I am facing this problem too, have you had some luck resolving this issue. I found another [unresolved thread](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg14798.html)

Comment: I ended up giving up on this issue. I do believe it is a problem with the rpi bluetooth module itself (I have heard that it is giving some problems). This kind of problem does not occur with other computers...

Comment: You could try updating bluez to a newer version. However I ended up using a UART Bluetooth LE profile for exchanging data between the pi and an iPhone App. https://scribles.net/updating-bluez-on-raspberry-pi-from-5-43-to-5-50/